# Table View Cell not become visible on device

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard, tableview

I am beginner with iOS application development so it may be that I am doing some easy mistake :)

At present in StoryBoard, I have added Table View and created Table View Cell within its child but when I run the application in Simulator, I found no entry of cell.

Also I tried with Table View Controller too because I read that you can't create static cells in Table View.

Please check the following screenshots:

**Table View Cell**

[image]

**Table View Controller**

[image]

I am stuck in both approaches.

Comment: can u show code of table delegate and dataSource

Comment: I am just using StoryBoard at present, no code I did - I want long list of items with header in page. Also all static items exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select static cells from content

[image]

to set height

[image]

Comment: Yes this problem get solve clearly :) One more question, can you tell me, how to set each cell height?

Comment: Yes it worked - one more question, can you tell me about how to fix the width as well? here is screenshot - https://drive.google.com/open?id=1DDC0f1hJf22UsUcDZAbCWvyR8uQ_bxso - just one more help please

Comment: set the trailing constraint of the light black content to trailing of contentView - 20

Comment: ContainerView already contains this kind of constraints: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1agrF2IGqTciPgE7KE0tUc8hjejJmtPjk

Comment: if u added it as a subview   to container make sure both have pinned to same leading and trailing'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164976/discussion-between-siddharth-and-sh-khan).